# iPad/Safari scroll keeps jumping to the top

Tags: ipad, safari, scroll

I have a simple  with overflow-y:scroll.   On the web it works fine, and the contents of the div scrolls.

But on iPad, some times when releasing the touch from a scroll it suddenly jumps to the top.  And every time when scrolling to the bottom.

This is also effecting an itunes store, in our meta tags, that displays a link to an app when 'bouncing' at the top.